# Overload << and >> to work well with pointers C++

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading

I am trying to add the these functions:

```
friend std::ostream& operator <<( std::ostream& outs, const TrashCan * drive );
friend std::istream& operator >>( std::istream& ins, TrashCan * & drive );
```

So it works properly with this driver code in main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include "TrashCan.h"


int main( ) {

using namespace std;

cout << "Welcome to my TrashCan Program!" << endl;

TrashCan myCan;
TrashCan yourCan;
TrashCan empty( 0, 0 );
TrashCan * ptrCan = new TrashCan( 0, 0 ); 
TrashCan * nullCan = NULL; 

// using overloaded operations for pointers...
cin >> ptrCan;
cin >> nullCan;  // 

cout << ptrCan << endl;
cout << nullCan << endl;  //
```

My Trashcan class constructor is as such:

```
TrashCan( int size, int contents );
```

I am familiar with overloading simple operations like + - and ≤ but am quite confused when it comes to overloading iostream functions so that they work with pointers. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the ultimate aim to provide a way of serializing these objects to/from disk?

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what is your actual question. Does this program compile? If not, what is the error message? Or are you asking about best practices?

Answer (score 1):

Although it is possible to just overload the input and output operators for pointers, I don't consider it to be a good idea in the first place: in C++ there is very little need to use pointers and there is no point in encouraging users to use operators. That is, the simple solution is: **don't** use pointers!

Conceptually, there is nothing different between overloading input or output operators for pointers compared to other types. That is, you'd just overload

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, TrashCan const* drive) {
    return *drive;
}
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, TrashCan* drive) {
    return *drive;
}
```

Both of the implementations just delegate to the corresponding reference version reducing the problem to a problem with a known solution (I/O with references to objects).

Comment: @DyP: ADL for built-in types, including pointers, doesn't go looking in interesting places. In partiuclar, it doesn't go looking in a namespace where the type of pointed to class is defined (if I recall correctly). With respect to not really being allowed: there are restrictions in Chapters 17 on what can be overloaded without involving user-defined types and since pointers count as built-in types these overload don't involve any user-defined types.

Comment: @DyP: Interesting. According to this clause pointers should contribute to the set of searched namespaces. I don't know why I had concluded that they wouldn't. I can't find any restrictions on the overloads, either. Seems, I'll need to revise my answer (although I'll stick to using pointers not being a good idea anwyay).

Answer (score 1):

I personally think it makes more sense to overload for `TrashCan` objects, and then dereference pointers at the place where you need to print the objects.

Without knowing much about your problem, I will propose that you need only one signature.

```
// Take const reference, not pointer
friend std::ostream& operator <<( std::ostream& outs, const TrashCan& drive );


TrashCan * ptrCan = new TrashCan( 0, 0 ); 
// [...]
std::cout << *ptrCan << endl;    // dereference.  no copies made.
```

Another benefit of having one function definition is that the code will be more maintainable, i.e. you won't have two overloads of a function that need to be maintained in parallel, or refactored to use the same code.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't overload operators for pointers. You should pass an object or a reference to that object.

They should declare like this:

```
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const TrashCan & drive );
std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& in, TrashCan  & drive );
```